# Embedding PowerBI: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'

Tags: powerbi

We are having a problem trying to embed Power BI reports residing in an specific Workspace (a O365 group).

We managed to successfuly embed reports from other workspaces without any issues. I had a look at the permissions of the workspace and I do not see anything different. In fact it has the same members as the other workspaces, and the account used to authenticate the application is the admin for all those workspaces.

The error we get is the following:

```
2017-10-12 16:07:44 +00:00 [Error] 0HL8HHCUA5TUI-Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware: An unhandled exception has occurred: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.Reports.<GenerateTokenInGroupWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.ReportsExtensions.<GenerateTokenInGroupAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.ReportsExtensions.GenerateTokenInGroup(IReports operations, String groupId, String reportKey, GenerateTokenRequest requestParameters)
```

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to open a support incident with Microsoft for this one. Apparently this was a bug on the service. The O365 group's permission has recently changed and it did not replicate correctly into the workspace -- even though it indicated in the PBI workspace that the right permissions were set. Support rep liaised with the PBI team to get this fixed.